# How to change height of Action bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using min API 14 I want to reduce height of action bar

code i used

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#fe9900</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">20dp</item>         
</style>
```

but **android:actionBarSize** is not working with API 14 
also used

`<item name="android:height">30dp</item>`

but not working
please help me resolve this

Comment: best explained here http://code2care.org/pages/change-height-of-android-actionbar/

Answer (score 1):

it will help you

```
<style name="thin_ab_style" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">  
   <item name="android:height">30dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: to make it work i added android:theme="@style/MyTheme" to my AndroidManifest file ..